# Hibernate using sequence generator and sequence in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have the following sequence:

[as seen now in Toad]:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE LOG_ID_SEQ
  START WITH 787585
  MAXVALUE 1000000000000000000000000000
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  NOORDER
/
```

I have the following table sequence generator:

```java
@SequenceGenerator(name="LOG_ID_SEQ", sequenceName="LOG_ID_SEQ")
@Id
@Column(name = "log_id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="LOG_ID_SEQ")
Long id;
```

The highest value of `log_id` is currently 39379151

Now the weird problem: the client created a dump of the poduction database 
and imported it in the test database.
When I tested the application I got a `ORA-00001` unique constraint error on this table.

When I imported the same dump and test the application on my machine I do not get that error??

How is this possible with Hibernate? I have no idea where or what to look for.

[UPDATED]:
To be accurate: after I imported the dump into a new schema locally the last sequence value in the dump was 39354002. Without resetting the sequence my next value is 39379151.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current highest value of `log_id` is 39379151, but you're re-creating the `LOG_ID_SEQ` in a new schema/database with a starting value of 787585, then the next new row inserted will have a `log_id` value that already exists.  You should probably alter your `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement to reflect the updated new max value for `log_id`.

Comment: On my local setup I get a new `log_id` value of 39379152 without resetting the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting values back from your sequence that collide with data in your table.

max(log_id) = 39,379,151, which is higher than your sequence "start with" value = 787,585.

Re-create your sequence with "start with" higher than max(log_id) and you should be all set.

The error may not be consistent because you may not be using every sequence value, so it's possible that on occasion inserts may succeed if you get a value that falls in a gap between existing rows.